# no connection to devices after "crash"

Tags: networking, usb, crash, ubuntu-16.04

short version: After my system crashed it seems that the kernel cannot connect to the devices any more.

long version: While working on my laptop I recognized that my wireless mouse did not work any more and thought its batteries run low. I didn't care since I wasn't expecting any device-problems and continued with the touchpad. After leaving my system (Ubunutu 16.04, kernel 4.4.0) running unattended and unused for a while (~5 hours; without shutdown) there was blackscreen and no response from the machine. After reboot I realized neither usb devices (mouse, wifi-adapter) nor the network run at all. Restarting the network services or rebooting didn't change anything.

Currently a live-usb rescues my data. I successfully mounted and accessed external hdds and connected to the internet with the live-usb, so there is no physical damage to the hardware. Back on the damaged system `lsusb` and `lspci` show the devices, that are not working, so the system also recognizes them. It seems that the devices are totally fine and just can't be accessed. 
Two days ago I installed PlayOnLinux and Path of Exile, which made some ugly graphic errors and system freezes.

Any suggestions?

I got the `syslog` stored. How can I attach it here?

Comment: Maybe a Kernel problem (after unrecognized update)? Can you revert to last kernel when booting (from bootloader)?

Comment: You are right @Ben. The previous kernel (4.4.0-42-generic) works fine, only the current one (4.4.0-43-generic) is broken. What are the next steps to repair the current kernel and what could have caused the problems?

Comment: I had a similar problem. Newest kernel did not work for me. I had to wait for the next kernel update. Until this time I had to use the older version. I don't think you need to repair anything...just wait few days for the next update.